# Repeated mentions of eggs in poems by Allen Ginsberg

Tags: poetry, symbolism, motif, allen-ginsberg

I've been listening to Allen Ginsberg reading his own poetry, and I've noticed a repeated mention of eggs in them. For examples:

> who plunged themselves under meat trucks looking for an egg

["Howl"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/49303/howl), Pt I

> America when will you send your eggs to India?

["America"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/49305/america-56d22b41f119f)

> While India starved and screamed and ate mad dogs full of rain
> and mountains of eggs were reduced to white powder in the halls of Congress
> no Godfearing man will walk there again because of the stink of the rotten eggs of America
> and the Indians of Chiapas continue to gnaw their vitaminless tortillas
> aborigines of Australia perhaps gibber in the eggless wilderness
> and I rarely have an egg for breakfast tho my work requires infinite eggs to come to birth in Eternity
> eggs should be eaten or given to their mothers

["Death To Van Gogh's Ear"](https://www.everseradio.com/death-to-van-goghs-ear-allen-ginsberg/)

To me that seems to be some sort of symbol that he uses as a personal stylistic or story telling tool. From a Jungian standpoint, the egg represents creation, life, birth, infinity, the sun, and unity. But that to me doesn't feel particularly right in the other context, nothing in the poems seems to connect the egg to anything in a way that those interpretations would fit.

**Are eggs a significant motif in Ginsberg's poetry? If so, why, and what do they signify?**

I could be over/under thinking it, but I'm definitely curious to see how everyone picks it apart.

Comment: What is your question? Literature Stack Exchange requires requires questions to be specific and focused, not open discussion threads about interesting observations.

Comment: Further to bobble's comment, I've edited your post to add a clear answerable question which seems to be what you really want to ask. Please let me know if I've captured the purpose of your question correctly or not.